# Would a life insurance company think I was teetotal if I said I didn't drink regularly?

Tags: united-kingdom, life-insurance

I have a life insurance policy and one of the application questions was "Do you regularly drink alcohol?". I answered "no", because to me it meant "do you drink every day?" or "do you drink every week?" and I can go for weeks or even months without drinking.

However, my colleague thinks this question really means "are you teetotal?" which I am not, and particularly over periods like Christmas I can drink a fair amount.

I would think if they wanted to know if I was teetotal, they would actually ask that. Who is right? I am concerned they may void any claim if they think I have lied.

Comment: Technically, if you have one drink a year on Christmas Day then you drink alcohol regularly, and if you binge 40 units on three nights a week on average, but on no particular schedule, then you _don't_ drink alcohol regularly.

Comment: @MikeScott Well this is my issue. Obviously the intent is to get an idea of how much you drink, but it's poorly worded at best. Someone like me with a very ordered and logical brain could very well make the claim you make, but would "I drink 40 units a week but on different days and at different times so therefore it's not regular." stand up in court?

Comment: Which life insurance company is asking this question?

Comment: @BenMiller https://www.beaglestreet.com/

Comment: The life insurance company may well refuse to pay out on a policy if you should die in a car accident in which you were one of the people involved (even if you were just a passenger in the car) and the post-mortem (autopsy for US readers) showed that you had been drinking, and especially so if the accident occurred within a year (or maybe two) after the policy was issued (same as with suicides). After that, the policy cannot be contested on the grounds of false declarations. After all, you might have taken up drinking after the policy was issued.  Continued....

Comment: @DilipSarwate I think you should post this as an answer. I have had the policy for nearly two years already. If have taken up drinking since, would I not be obliged to inform them?

Comment: Continuation...  The question is used more for setting the _premium_ charged for the policy; those who drink regularly, or binge on large amounts but only on Christmas, Easter, St. Crispin's Day, and Michaelmas, have lower life expectancies than those who are more abstemious, and so the former should be charged larger premiums.

Comment: The definition of "reguarly" will defined in the t&cs of the insurance company. So it'll vary.

Comment: @Liam It is not. There is no mention of alcohol consumption in any of the documents I have except the one summarising the responses I gave.

Comment: Well there is no legal definition of "regularly" so it'll have to be written down somewhere. Just because your insurance company states that one drink per week is infrequent, another might state one per month.

Comment: @liam Or what if someone says, "Regularly? No. I often go several hours without a drink."

Comment: @Liam “Regularly” and “frequently” are not synonyms. A question about how regularly you drink is not a question about how frequently you drink.

Comment: http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/57/57320139579da85533680af5ec9c180f73e115648018e4995c9f5fd08e5aed16.jpg

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I spoke to their help line (anonymously) and the call centre agent stated they consider regular to be at least one drink per week. If I don't drink that often I can legitimately say I don't drink regularly.

Comment: [As stated](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/90100/would-a-life-insurance-company-think-i-was-teetotal-if-i-said-i-didnt-drink-reg?noredirect=1#comment157785_90100), I'd say this is that companies definition, this may or may not apply to other companies

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a legal question, and I am not a lawyer, but:

I'd say common sense says that if they ask, "Do you drink alcohol regularly?" that is different from "Do you drink alcohol at all?"

It's a poor question because "regularly" is a vague qualifier. As others have noted, does "regularly" mean "every day"? "Every week"? "At least twice a year"? Etc. If this went to court I would think the company would have a hard time proving that someone deliberately lied on the application because his idea of "regularly" was different from what the insurance company had in mind.

I've had insurance applications where they ask, say, "Do you have an average of more than two drinks of alcohol per week?" That's a much more concrete question.

And just by the way, my favorite alcohol consumption question ever: "Has anyone ever annoyed you by complaining about your drinking?" Of course if someone says, "Yeah, my wife is always nagging me about my drinking. But I have it totally under control", I think it's a fair guess that he's an alcoholic. I wonder how many people fall for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is really a personal finance question. Legally, for you to lie, you have to make a false statement of fact. What constitutes "regularly" is a matter of opinion, and therefore statements regarding the matter are not statements of fact. If you drink every day, maybe they could make a claim that you lied, but if there's any reasonable ambiguity, it has to be resolved in favor of you. So a competent lawyer should be able to force them to pay. Whether you or your heirs will be able to afford a lawyer is another matter

Comment: I checked the help centre before posting and life insurance questions are on-topic.